# Selenium IDE automatically inserts selectWindow command

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a problem using Selenium IDE.

Whenever I right-click on an element which I want to verify with Selenium, then select the verification command I want to use, Selenium IDE automatically inserts a selectWindow command with target that seems to be a random sequence of numbers.

When I run the test, it fails to commit that selectWindow command and fails.

Is there a way to stop Selenium from automatically inserting the selectWindow command?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you delete that command and try running your test?

Comment: I do delete that but it is really annoying having to delete it after every action I make